# Magento 2 - Move product custom options section before product Price

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I want to move the product custom options section before product price. How can I achieve that? i have used move element but did not get

Thanks

Comment: Can you show how you have tried so far?

Comment: i have applied this but not working ..<move element="product.info.price" destination="product.info.form.options"  before="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom"/>

Answer (score 1):

You can not move the Options outside to the form. But you can Move the price section under the options. to Archive this you have to add the below code in

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info.price" destination="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Check the below image**

[image]

Comment: I have applied your code..its working for product who have custom options ..but for a product which does not have the custom option..in that case, price is getting hidden.@kishor Thummar

Comment: @HemangiPatel are you able to solve it because i am also getting same issue without custom option products have price is hidden